Does select_item always precedes add_to_cart?
What if you can add_to_cart from an item list - do you still have to send the select_item event before the add to cart fires? Or just add_to_cart?
Apparently it is googles best practice to send the select_item event before to keep the breadcrumb of  view->select->add to cart

I guess you are asking for the scenario that is user can add_to_cart from a product list right? Because add_to_cart can happen in many place. One is in product detail page. Another is maybe directly from product list page.

Yes, that is correct. In our current setup the select_item event autofires before add_to_cart when adding from a product list, which prevents us from calculating the real CTR to product page.
